# How do I create and publish 'npm create' scripts?

Tags: javascript, shell, npm, yarnpkg

I'd like to create and publish on npm a script that runs in a similar way of:

```bash
npm create qwik@latest
```

or

```
yarn create next-app --typescript
```

but I don't know how to start. I googled a lot but with no results.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start your package's name with `create-`

Examples:

```
create-qwik
```

```
create-react-app
```

```
create-next-app
```